# Automatic SQL Server 2005 Backup

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am not really a DB guy. We don't have any back up servers for our DataBase. There is a need for some kind of back up service which can take production back up daily once in the morning and once in the evening .

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need basic backups they can be setup pretty easily from the maintenance plan interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658%28SQL.90%29.aspx

This link is more "wizardy"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189036%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: that doesnt work for SQLExpress editions, by the way.  only for full server editions.

Answer (score 0):

I use redgates [SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Backup/index_v2.htm), it's worked for years very reliably, easy to set up, and it does streaming compression, so your backups don't take too much disk space.